# JS - Check for existence of a value in array and if true assign a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, indexof

I am checking for the existence of a certain value in a array and if it's there I want to assign a value that that is specific for the value from the myArray. The code below works, but there is a lot of repetition. Is there a better way of doing things?

```
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const aExists = myArray.indexOf('a') > -1;
const bExists = myArray.indexOf('b') > -1;
const cExists = myArray.indexOf('c') > -1;

return [
    (aExists ? 'value-for-a' : undefined),
    (bExists ? 'or-something-for-b' : undefined),
    (cExists ? 'different-value-for-c' : undefined)
].filter(x => x !== undefined).toString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary (`dict`) of keys/values. Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and iterate the keys with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Find the existence of the keys in `myArray` using [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), and add the matching key from `dict` to the result:

```js
const dict = {
  'a': 'value-for-a',
  'b': 'or-something-for-b',
  'c': 'different-value-for-c'
};
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const result = Object.keys(dict)
  .reduce((r, k) => {
    if(myArray.includes(k)) r.push(dict[k]);
  
    return r;
  }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just simply need to create a mapper for all pre-specified values and filter `myArray` by checking the existance of its key in the mapper. Then use `map` to create a new array with expected values included.

```js
let myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let values = {
  a: 'value-for-a',
  b: 'or-something-for-b',
  c: 'different-value-for-c'
};
let results = myArray.filter(v => values[v]).map(v => values[v]);
console.log(results);
```

If you want a faster solution, then you can use this instead.

```js
let myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let values = {
  a: 'value-for-a',
  b: 'or-something-for-b',
  c: 'different-value-for-c'
};
let results =[];
for(let v of myArray) {
  if(!values[v]) continue;
  results.push(values[v]);
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing is to use a series of `if`s

```
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
if (myArray.indexOf('a') > -1) {
    return 'value-for-a';
}
if (myArray.indexOf('b') > -1) {
    return 'or-something-for-b';
}
if (myArray.indexOf('c') > -1) {
    return 'different-value-for-c';
}
return '';
```

or a map of values and a loop

```
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const values = {a: 'value-for-a', b: 'or-something-for-b', c: 'different-value-for-c'};
for (const key of Object.keys(values)) {
    if (myArray.indexOf(key)) {
        return values[key];
    }
}
return '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a object data structure for which you want to check the index in the array and get the new values. When the index for that key exist in the array `myArray` then you can simply push the value corresponding to that index in your result array:

```js
const mapObj = {
  'a': 'value-for-a',
  'b': 'or-something-for-b',
  'c': 'different-value-for-c'
};
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

var res = [];
Object.keys(mapObj).forEach((key)=>{
  if(myArray.indexOf(key) !== -1){
    res.push(mapObj[key]);
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

> Also, I would suggest to use `indexOf()` instead of `includes()` as `includes()`
>   will give you error in IE browser.
>    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Make an object for the desired new array's possible values, and then iterate through its entries to transform it to the desired format:

```js
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const newArrValues = {
  a: 'value-for-a',
  b: 'or-something-for-b',
  c: 'different-value-for-c',
};
const result = Object.entries(newArrValues)
  .filter(([key]) => myArray.includes(key))
  .map(([_, value]) => value)
  .toString();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and filter the items of the array with an object for the wanted strings and map then the values.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'd'];
    data = {
        a: 'value-for-a',
        b: 'or-something-for-b',
        c: 'different-value-for-c',
        e: 'foo'
     },
     result = array
         .filter(k => k in data)
         .map(k => data[k]);
     
console.log(result);
```